# Logging USB vendor id (vid) and product id (pid)

Tags: macos, usb, virtualbox

I have a USB device that renumerates several times, each time with a different vendor id and product id. I'd like to use this device within a Linux VM on my OS X host. I've managed to setup a vid/pid filter for two of these renumerated vid/pid combinations, but one is so brief that I can't catch it. Is there a way I can see a history of USB vendor/product ids that connected and disconnected from the system on OS X? Or another way of figuring this out perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a utility for this:

https://gist.github.com/thinkski/0ebc53ab4989d904a04c

Answer (score 0):

The kernel generally prints a message whenever it finds a new USB device, and I think it would have the VID and PID in it.  Try running `dmesg` to look at these messages.

Comment: The Linux kernel does yes, but in this case Linux is only running within the VM -- the VM needs to forward the device from OS X to the VM, and I need to tell it which VID and PID to forward. Does OS X have an equivalent of dmesg? I didn't see any similar messages within Console.

Comment: Mac OS X is very similar to Linux and it has dmesg: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/dmesg.8.html

Comment: So it does, however I don't see USB attach/detach events with a uid/vid reported in there as in Linux.